# argparse - How to handle parent parser behaviour?

Tags: python, inheritance, argparse

I have a parent parser which defines a common flag `--global` which is globally available across subparsers.

```
     parent (defines --global)
    /      \
child1      child2
--global    --global
```

I am handling the flags of `child1` and `child2` via [set_dfault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults). Since both subparsers inherit `--global` I have to handle the flag in both subparser functions. How can I improve this? Can I define the behaviour of `--global` in `parent` once without repeating me?

```py
parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument("--global", action="store_true")

def handle_child1(xargs):
    if xargs.global:
        print("handle global")
    print("do stuff from child 1")
        

def handle_child2(yargs):
    if yargs.global:
        print("handle global")
    print("do stuff from child 2")

subparser = parser.add_subparsers()
child1 = subparser.add_parser("c1", parents=[parent])
subparse_x.set_defaults(func=handle_child1)

child2 = subparser.add_parser("c2", parents=[parent])
subparse_y.set_defaults(func=handle_child2)
```

As you can see I have to handle `global` in each subparser. Not idea. Of cause I could call a function `handle_global` from each subparser to make this a bit better. However is there a solution that just lets `parent` handle `global`?

Comment: Does `--global` behave *differently* for the subparsers, or do you just want to provide the flexibility of specifying `--global` before or after the subcommand?

Comment: Unstated, but I assume you are doing the usual `parse_args` and `args.func(args)`.  What you do with `args` after parsing is purely part of your code organization.  The `parser` has done its job. During development I recommend adding a `print(args)`, to see what's in it.  Whether it makes more sense to "handle" `args.global` outside of `args.func` is purely up to you; it depends on what you are using it for.  If it is used by all subparsers, you might consider making a `parser.add_argument('--global'...)` instead (but don't try to define it at both levels).

Comment: By the way, the use of the `parents` is just a convenience that may save some typing.  It doesn't add any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are attempting to do you can handle the global attribute prior to sending the arguments to the correct sub-command function.

```py
import argparse

def handle_global_flag():
    print("handling --global")

def handle_child1(args):
    print(args)
    print("do stuff from child 1")

def handle_child2(args):
    print(args)
    print("do stuff from child 2")

parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument("--global", action="store_true")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")

child1 = subparsers.add_parser("c1", parents=[parent])
child1.set_defaults(func=handle_child1)

child2 = subparsers.add_parser("c2", parents=[parent])
child2.set_defaults(func=handle_child2)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.command is not None:
    if getattr(args, "global"):
        handle_global_flag()
    args.func(args)
else:
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit()
```

Comment: Not sure if that works. I would like to be able to call `--global` from anywhere. Like `program --global` or `program c1 --global` or `program c2 --global`